# Error reading with HTML Forms

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to read data from a form with javascript.

Here's my code so far.

```
<form id="frm1">
 Your text: <input type="text" name="fname"><br><br>
 </form> 
<button onclick="myFunction()">Go!</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var myStr;
myStr = document.getElementById("frm1");;
var myStrL = myStr.length;
var i = myStrL;
console.log(myStr.substring(0,i));
var i = i - 1;
for (i = 0; i < myStrL; i++) {
console.log(myStr.substring(0,i));
document.write(myStr.substring(0,i));
document.write ("<br>");
}
var i = myStrL + 1;
document.write(myStr.substring(0,i));
document.write ("<br>");
}
</script>
</body>
```

Tough when I press the "Go" Button, Nothing happens, Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Check the console. Also using `document.write` like that will overwrite your DOM.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form id="frm1">
 Your text: <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
 </form> 
<button onclick="myFunction()">Go!</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var myStr;
myStr = document.getElementById("fname").value;
console.log(myStr);
var myStrL = myStr.length;
var i = myStrL;
console.log(myStr.substring(0,i));
var i = i - 1;
for (i = 0; i < myStrL; i++) {
console.log(myStr.substring(0,i));
document.write(myStr.substring(0,i));
document.write ("<br>");
}
var i = myStrL + 1;
document.write(myStr.substring(0,i));
document.write ("<br>");
}
</script>
```

This will work. You were targeting wrong element

https://jsfiddle.net/vb6cab14/